# Android get ListView sub item from another sub item

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I'm using this way to make my ListView item's dropdown menu.

Here's my item's XML

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
  <TableLayout ...>
    <Something like TextView, ImageView... />
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnMenu"... />
  </TableLayout>

  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/dropMenu" android:visibility="gone" ...>
    <Some other Button... />
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So in "getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGoup parent)", when user click "btnMenu", I'll set the "dropMenu" visible, and that looks like a dropdown menu.

My question is

1. First I click 4th item, make its dropdown menu shows
2. Second, I click 6th item, make its dropdown menu shows, but the 4th item's dropdown menu should be set "gone".

Here's I did tried but not work

```
View lastView=getChildAt(lastIndex);
lastView.findViewById(R.id.dropMenu).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

How can I operate 4th list item when I actually in 6th list item ?

Comment: see belove link ,i think it is expandable list view http://www.coderzheaven.com/expandable-listview-android-simpleexpandablelistadapter-simple-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement using ExpandAnimation.

[image]

[image]

ExpandListItem.java

```
package com.list.animation;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

public class ExpandListItem extends Animation {
    private View mAnimatedView;
    private LayoutParams mViewLayoutParams;
    private int mMarginStart, mMarginEnd;
    private boolean mIsVisibleAfter = false;
    private boolean mWasEndedAlready = false;

    /**
     * Initialize the animation
     * @param view The layout we want to animate
     * @param duration The duration of the animation, in ms
     */
    public ExpandListItem(View view, int duration) {

        setDuration(duration);
        mAnimatedView = view;
        mViewLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

        // decide to show or hide the view
        mIsVisibleAfter = (view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);

        mMarginStart = mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin;
        mMarginEnd = (mMarginStart == 0 ? (0- view.getHeight()) : 0);

        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);

        if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {

            // Calculating the new bottom margin, and setting it
            mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin = mMarginStart
                    + (int) ((mMarginEnd - mMarginStart) * interpolatedTime);

            // Invalidating the layout, making us seeing the changes we made
            mAnimatedView.requestLayout();

        // Making sure we didn't run the ending before (it happens!)
        } else if (!mWasEndedAlready) {
            mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin = mMarginEnd;
            mAnimatedView.requestLayout();

            if (mIsVisibleAfter) {
                mAnimatedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            mWasEndedAlready = true;
        }
    }
}
```

For complete implementation go through the below post

http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-listview-with-animation.html

Hope this will help you.. Thanks